# Annotations for MKLocalSearch in Swift 3 — Map View Current Location

Tags: swift, swift3

This is my first time on Stack Overflow. I have been trying to make an app that finds the user's current location and outputs the information the doctors close to the user. So far, I can find the current location, however, I am not able to add an annotation for the doctors near the current location.

Here is my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations[0]
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)

        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)

        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.map.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = "doctor"

        request.region = map.region

        let localSearch:MKLocalSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        localSearch.start(completionHandler: {(result, error) in

            for placemark in (result?.mapItems)! {
                if(error == nil) {

                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(placemark.placemark.coordinate.latitude, placemark.placemark.coordinate.longitude)
                    annotation.title = placemark.placemark.name
                    annotation.subtitle = placemark.placemark.title
                    self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)

                }
                else
                {
                    print(error ?? 0)
                }
            }
        })
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

All responses are appreciated and if you have any advice for what I should do next time I ask a question, please leave it down below. Thank you.

Comment: Learning to format the question would be a good first step.

Comment: Sorry but thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Your map view needs a delegate with a `map​View(_:​view​For:​)` implementation. Otherwise, adding an annotation will have no visible effect.

Answer (score 0):

To add an annotation you need to inherit `MKMapViewDelegate`. 
Then add: `mapView.delegate = self`  to your initialization method.
And implement this functions:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if !(view.annotation! is MKUserLocation) {
        let customPin = view.annotation as! CustomPin //if u wanna use custom pins

        configureDetailView(annotationView: view, spotPin: customPin.spotDetailsItem) //configuring view for tap
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    if !(annotation is CustomPin) {
        return nil
    }

    let identifier = "CustomPin"

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    } else {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

configureDetailView method and other information you can find [here](https://github.com/Pulichev/SpotMapIOs/blob/VladPulichev/SpotMap/Controllers/MainFormController.swift) (its is quite cumbersome)